# How can I structure a Composable to only trigger recomposition once?

Tags: kotlin, android-jetpack-compose, compose-recomposition

I'm working on a Composable that updates text after getting an HTTP response, and I'm trying to figure out a way to structure my Composables so that when recomposition occurs, it doesn't repeat the `loadJson` call.

```
@Composable
fun Schedule() {
    var textToShow by remember { mutableStateOf("loading...") }

    RemoteConfig.loadJson("schedule.api",
        onSuccess = { routes ->
            textToShow = routes[1].jsonObject.toString()
        },
        onError = { e ->
            textToShow = "Failed to load bus schedule.\n($e)"
        }
    )

    Text(textToShow)
}
```

I'm using `remember` to prevent recomposition if the text doesn't change, but `loadJson` still gets called twice-- once the first time the Composable is drawn, and again when `textToShow`'s value is updated. If the HTTP response was different every time, recomposition would be triggered indefinitely. I believe it boils down to these being in the same scope, but I'm having a hard time restructuring it to do what I want. I'd love to see examples of better approaches.

Comment: Not a complete answer, but relevant docs: https://developer.android.com/jetpack/compose/side-effects

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow! If the answer below resolved your problem, you can upvote it or accept it by clicking the green check mark to the left of the answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could try to use a [`LaunchedEffect`](https://developer.android.com/jetpack/compose/side-effects#launchedeffect). It allows executing asynchronous code at the moment that the Composable enters into the composition. It is not called again at recompositions.

You can adjust your code like this:

```
@Composable
fun Schedule() {
    var textToShow by remember { mutableStateOf("loading...") }

    LaunchedEffect(Unit) { // by providing Unit, it only will be executed once
        // this is a Coroutine Scope, so you could also call suspend functions here
        RemoteConfig.loadJson("schedule.api",
            onSuccess = { routes ->
                textToShow = routes[1].jsonObject.toString()
            },
            onError = { e ->
                textToShow = "Failed to load bus schedule.\n($e)"
            }
        )
    }

    Text(textToShow)
}
```

As a side note, you could consider to delegate the logic to a [ViewModel](https://developer.android.com/codelabs/basic-android-kotlin-compose-viewmodel-and-state#4) instead, and only pass the UI state (loading, success, error) to the Composable.